# How to use MSBuild with TFS and SSIS

Tags: tfs, ssis, msbuild

I'm a complete novice in using TFS Build definition and MSBuild scripts.

I want to automate my SSIS build and deployments and create a build definition which will build and deploy my SSIS project whenever I queue it up.

I found this project:  http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/82369

which allows you to create a DLL which you can place in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`

Then you can call the SSIS.MSBuild.proj (See end for this) with certain parameters like this in a visual studio command line:

```
MSBuild SSIS.MSBuild.proj /t:SSISBuild,SSISDeploy /p:SSISProj="MySSISProject",Configuration="DEV",,SSISServer="AB-CDE-FGH-I1\DEV",ProjectName="MySSISProject"
```

or I can put it in a BAT file like this:

```
%systemroot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe SSIS.MSBuild.proj /t:SSISBuild,SSISDeploy /p:SSISProj="MySSISProject",Configuration="DEV",,SSISServer="AB-CDE-FGH-I1\DEV",ProjectName="MySSISProject"
```

It works fine when you run the BAT file, it builds and deploys the SSIS project.

Questions:

1. How can I use this so it is automated, so I can manually kick off a build and deployment from within VS/TFS?  Using a build definition.
2. How can I ensure the correct configurations are selected, and the correct destination server?  For example we have SSIS configurations for DEV, SIT, SYS, UAT, PRD.  Each with its own server name.  Do I need a separate build definition for each environment or is there a way to use one build definition?
3. Anything useful in using powershell somehow?

Here is SSIS.MSBuild.proj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Project  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
          DefaultTargets="SSISBuild;SSISDeploy">
  <!--Requires a property called $(SSISProj) to be defined when this script is called-->
  <UsingTask TaskName="DeploymentFileCompilerTask" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Build.dll" />
  <Target Name="SSISBuild" Condition="'$(SSISProj)' != ''">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SSISProjPath>$(SSISProj)\$(SSISProj).dtproj</SSISProjPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="**************Building SSIS project: $(SSISProjPath) for configuration: $(CONFIGURATION)**************" />
    <DeploymentFileCompilerTask
      InputProject="$(SSISProjPath)"
      Configuration="$(CONFIGURATION)"
      ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive">
    </DeploymentFileCompilerTask>
  </Target>

  <UsingTask TaskName="DeployProjectToCatalogTask" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Build.dll" />
  <Target Name="SSISDeploy" Condition="'$(SSISProj)' != ''">
    <Message Text="**************Publishing SSIS project: $(SSISProj) to: $(SSISServer) to folder: $(PROJECTNAME)**************" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ISPac>$(SSISProj)\bin\$(CONFIGURATION)\$(SSISProj).ispac</ISPac>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <DeployProjectToCatalogTask
          DeploymentFile="$(ISPac)"
          Instance="$(SSISServer)"
          Folder="$(PROJECTNAME)"
          CreateFolder="true"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

***EDIT*** I tried adding some MSBuild Arguments to the TFS Build Definition.  I tried various combinations of arguments, some with quotes, some without.  I couldn't get it to work.

```
"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Buildssis\SSIS.MSBuild.proj" /t:SSISBuild,SSISDeploy /p:SSISProj="MySSISProject",Configuration="SIT",SSISServer="AB-CDE-FGH-I1\DEV",ProjectName="MySSISProject"
```

But I always get this error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: C:\Users\me\Desktop\Buildssis\SSIS.MSBuild.proj

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

Comment: in the Build process template editor, do you pass in MSBuild Arguments?

Comment: I am getting this error when running my build definition: MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: C:\Users\me\Desktop\Buildssis\SSIS.MSBuild.proj

Comment: the error is when I try this line in my MSBuild Arguments: "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Buildssis\SSIS.MSBuild.proj" /t:SSISBuild,SSISDeploy /p:SSISProj="MySSISProject",Configuration="SIT",SSISServer="AB-CDE-FGH-I1\DEV",ProjectName="MySSISProject"

Comment: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe C:\Users\me\Desktop\Buildssis\SSIS.MSBuild.proj /t:SSISBuild /p:SSISProj="MySSISProject",Configuration="SIT"` Provide an explicit path to the .NET framework, does that improve the situation.

Comment: do you need to add the command MSBuild.exe in the TFS Build definition MSBuild Arguments?  I will try and see...

Comment: I was proposing you do that on your local machine to verify you have the correct syntax for the msbuild call. After that, then you can compare to the TFS version and that should help get things aligned

Comment: I tried and got the same error...

Comment: Tried from command line or tried it via the TFS build component?

Comment: apologies - it works fine in the command line (visual studio command prompt), my BAT file works also.  Just not when I try the TFS MSBuild Arguments

Comment: Just to verify, you do have the DLL installed on the TFS server, right?

Comment: ha that could be an issue.  I won't have access to do that.  For some reason I thought it would call the dll from my local machine on which I was doing the build

Comment: Please vote here if you think it's about time for MSBuild to support SSxS projects: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/523612/support-ssis-ssrs-ssas-in-msbuild.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are prety close about the solution. you can call your package in console application and set the variables there. And for different DEV, SIT, SYS, UAT, PRD. you can have configuration file for the the console application. and then you can set the package variables in the console app. I hope it solve the preoblem. As much i could understand.

Please let me know if this is not related to your problem then explain your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the best way would be to use an UpgradeBuildTemplate for your team build.

Modify the build script to calls the tasks that you have created in the "AfterCompile" target of the build. See below

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You can pass build parameters in your team build definition. If you edit your build definition and edit Process, you will see option to pass MSBuild Arguments.

Comment: Ok I'll do that, when a user checks in code, Joe would it know whether to use SIT, SYS etc? I.e. how to automate it, or would it have to be manual

Comment: You can default it to the DEV, with manual build triggers for SIT, SYS, etc. Usually, each check-in requires a BVT, which you can trigger with the CI build. You take informed decision of deploying a build for System Integration Testing or System Testing, which you can trigger manually